# Отследить изменяется ли  данное-член класса

Tags: ооп, c++

В цикле вектор очищается, а потом заполняется новыми значениями. Есть ли способы отследить его изменение, кроме как сохранять копию, а потом сравнивать с новым.

Comment: Нужно сравнивать заполненные векторы между собой?

Answer (score 1):

Только хранить. Если ты его затрёшь, то с чем сравнивать будешь? Машина за тебя это никак не запомнит.

Answer (score 0):

У вектора есть длина (размер)

```
вектор.size();
```

сравнивай размеры

Comment: Размер может не измениться, значения да.

Comment: тогда используйте флаги модифицированности (тип bool)

Answer (score 0):

С большой долей вероятности можно отследить, использовав какой-то дайджест - ну, там, CRC32, когда ложное срабатывание не так важно, как скорость, или sha256, если наоборот.